# regex code to find email address within HTML script webscraping

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract phone, address and email from couple of corporate websites through webscraping

My code for that is as follows

```
l = 'https://www.zimmermanfinancialgroup.com/about'
address_t = []
phone_num_t = []

    # make a request to the link
response = requests.get(l)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
#soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')


phone_regex = "(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}"
    # extract the phone number information
match = soup.findAll(string=re.compile(phone_regex))

if match:
    print("Found the matching string:", match)
else:
    print("Matching string not found")

# extract email address information

mail = "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,7}\b"

match_a = soup.findAll(string=re.compile(mail))


match_a
```

The above code is working fine and it extracts phone number correctly, but it's not able to detect email address, same issue with other website (https://www.benefitexperts.com/about-us/)

Comment: Your email regex is hopelessly naive, and contains some common beginner regex errors. The email RFC contains a regex which actually covers all valid email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail address you are looking for is located at href attribute of (if it exist) an   tag as a string 'mailto:somemail@adrress.com'.
So you need just to pass href as keyword argument to the findall function so it will match all nodes having href as attribute and match the regulare expression.

check more about keyword arguments at the  BeautifulSoup official docs
https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find_all#the-keyword-arguments

Or simply

```
match_a = soup.findAll(href=re.compile(mail))
```

you do some clean up to extract exactly mail address

```
match_a = [a['href'].strip('mailto:') for a in match_a]
```

Comment: But it might not always be in "mailto" section of the page right.

Comment: there are two possibilities it may be anchored as <a href='mailto:example@mail.me' >some text</a> or as a text node . So you check theme both : if  soup.findAll(href=re.compile(mail)) is None check soup.findAll(string=re.compile(mail))  ,alternatively you could do a regex match to the whole html without parsing it ( response.content)